# why the javascript code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("myMessage").innerHTML = "hello,world!";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id=="myMessage"></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

when i run the file, there is no `hello,world!` output. why?

Comment: Please post your actual code. Editing your question every 20 seconds with fixed code as answers come in does not help identify what's wrong.

Comment: i am sorry, i have posted the whole code. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Your script block shoul be in the `<head>` or `<body>`, not outside either.</strike>

It's hard to keep track of your question with you editing it every 20 seconds.

Your latest problem appears to be this

```
<h1 id=="myMessage"></h1>
```

It should be

```
<h1 id="myMessage"></h1>
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/3Xzka/

Comment: i am sorry, i have some typos before. <h1 id=="myMessage"></h1> is the same as <h1 id="myMessage"></h1>.

Comment: No, it's not. The former has a double-equals sign, the latter, only one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, because you are identifying your code as "javescript" rather than "javascript".

**Edit:** This reply looks silly now but it answers the original question (before being edited). I was curious and actually tested it: none of my browsers (Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer... not even IE6) handle a `<script>` tag as JavaScript code if it's tagged as something else, such as:

```
<script type="text/javescript"></script>
                      ^
```

JavaScript is the *default* scripting engine, so this does work:

```
<script></script>
```

But the `type` attribute is obeyed when present.

Answer (score 0):

the `script` should be in the `body` tag or between `head` tags...

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that there is only one element on the page called `myMessage`? Having more than one will cause `getElementById()` to fail.